# How to change to multiple images upload https://github.com/alphayowakarindi/laravel9-vue3-blog

Tags: laravel, image, vue.js, upload, display

I followed this tutorial and it works fine, but now during create post I want to upload several images, then one image. How do I do this? Here is my code:

```
**CreatePost.vue**
` <label for="image1"><span>Image 1</span></label>
  <input type="file" :id="'image1'" @change="grabFile(1)" />
  <span v-if="errors.files && errors.files[0]" class="error">{{ errors.files[0] }}</span>
  <div class="preview">
    <img :src="urls[0]" alt="" />
  </div>`
```

I tried to change the create post table by adding imagePath2, ImagePath3, ImagePath4 and it creates columns inside table, but how do I send and get them for display. Could you please help and check these repositories?

```
`Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('imagePath');
        $table->string('imagePath2');
        $table->string('imagePath3');
        $table->string('imagePath4');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });`
```

Comment: Controllers are were all the magic happens. Go back to this tutorial and look at the `PostContoller#store`. This is where the values are taken from browser and saved to the database & storage.